# Blockchain parser for transaction level details

Tags: blockchain

I'm looking for transaction level data for both inputs and outputs. The [znort block parser](https://github.com/znort987/blockparser) returns the type of data I'm looking for, however it doesn't seem to detect multisig transactions. Has anyone updated the code?

There's another parser written by [John Ratcliff](https://code.google.com/p/blockchain/) which properly detects the multisig transactions, however this does not return transaction level data. Has anyone modified this code to return individual inputs and outputs?

Are there any other parsers available to return transaction level data for inputs and outputs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for a blockchain explorer. Insight, by BitPay, works pretty well and is open-source: https://github.com/bitpay/insight

Comment: Is Insight used only for web purposes?  I'm looking for something that will allow me to do data analysis, primarily something that I can read into R, Python, or SQL.  Can I get that sort of information from Insight?

Comment: it has a json http api so you can easily interface with it using any language

Comment: Gotcha. My problem with Insight is that I'll be working on a server, and I don't have permission to install Node.

Assuming I could install it, any idea of how long would it take to download all the data?